# Переменные в :root

Tags: css, css3, html5, root, css-variables

В чем разница объявление css переменных в :root и в html или другом селекторе?

В чем преимущество использование именно root?

Comment: [CSS custom properties placement :root vs body/html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060331/2881286)

Comment: Спасибо большое